# Targeting different mobile versions in layout

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've been trying the following to target my mobile lumia 920 in my layout.

```
<!--[if IEMobile]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/windowsPhone.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IEMobile 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/windowsPhone.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IEMobile 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/windowsPhone.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/windowsPhone.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

None of these works. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because this code works only in Windows Phone 7 and Lumia 920 is Windows Phone 8. Read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/iemobile-conditional-comment/)

Comment: So i wont be able to target Windows Phone 8 at all?

Comment: You can target but with jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JS to detect the browser.

```
browserUA = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (browserUA.search('windows phone os 7') > -1)
   //Load WP 7 CSS file
```